# How to deploy discuz forum on k8s cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Basically I want to deploy a discuz forum to my k8s cluster with below image
https://hub.docker.com/r/skyzhou/docker-discuz/

the mysql image is easy to deploy but the discuz forum doesn't provide any env variable for me to inject for datase, it is only allowed for links parameter,

The question is on k8s cluster there is no such way for me to inject this, so it is stuck.

The wordpress blog could expose the db-host and db_password parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP`](https://github.com/skyzhou/docker-discuz/blob/12eb5ef81ec1af88065f9209328417ccc46305cd/docker-entrypoint.sh#L4) variable is used in a misleading way, as one can see where it is stripped of the leading `tcp://` and used as [`DISCUZ_DB_HOST`](https://github.com/skyzhou/docker-discuz/blob/12eb5ef81ec1af88065f9209328417ccc46305cd/docker-entrypoint.sh#L40)

Thus, I would expect:

```
containers:
- name: discuz
  image: skyzhou/docker-discuz
  env:
  - name: MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP
    value: $(SERVICE_MYSQL_HOST):$(SERVICE_MYSQL_PORT)
```

should do the trick if you already have a `mysql` Service in kubernetes, or simply fill in the host and port if you already know them

Comment: Wow! Appreciate. It works in the first phase. Why the k8s yaml file has such strong format requirment:  I initially put the image first it gave me error which is non-sense

Comment: New error come i guess    i need to add another env 
error: missing required DISCUZ_DB_PASSWORD environment variable
  Did you forget to -e DISCUZ_DB_PASSWORD=... ?
   (Also of interest might be DISCUZ_DB_USER and DISCUZ_DB_NAME.)

Comment: Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "discuz-deployment.yaml": Deployment in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: [pos 309]: json: expect char '"' but got char '3'
@Mattew initial error which is non-sense

Comment: _Why the k8s yaml file has such strong format requirement_ that is a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: _Also of interest might be DISCUZ_DB_USER and DISCUZ_DB_NAME_, yes, as are [clearly shown](https://github.com/skyzhou/docker-discuz/blob/12eb5ef81ec1af88065f9209328417ccc46305cd/docker-entrypoint.sh#L42-L45) in the shell script I linked to

Comment: _Deployment in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: [pos 309]: json: expect char '"' but got char '3'_ without seeing the file, hard to troubleshoot that one, but you don't need stackoverflow to help you write legal yaml; there are an unbelievable number of resources to help with that

Comment: this is the error that I made a different sequence of name and image that's where confusing

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully deployed to my cluster and the port is set to 80 though I wish to expose it to 8080 not sure how.@Matthew L Daniel